# Proof with invertible matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B,C$ be matrix of the same size, and suppose A is invertible, Prove that

$(A-B)C=BA^{-1}$ then $C(A-B)=A^{-1}B$

I tried to prove it as following.

$(A-B)C=BA^{-1}$ implies

$AC-BC=BA^{-1}$ so

$ACA-BCA=B$ taking $A^{-1}$

$CA-A^{-1}BCA=A^{-1}B$

Any hint will be appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assume that $(A-B)C = BA^{-1}$. Then $A-B$ is invertible, and its inverse is $C+A^{-1}$. You can check:

$$ (A-B)(A^{-1}+C) = \mathrm{Id} + AC -BA^{-1} -BC = \mathrm{Id} + \bigg( (A-B)C - BA^{-1} \bigg) $$

But the assumption implies that the part in parentheses is zero, so this product is just the identity matrix. Inverse matrices always commute. By that I mean $X X^{-1} = X^{-1}X$ whenever $X$ is invertible. So you can re-arrange the product above in the opposite order:

$$ (A^{-1} + C)(A-B) = \mathrm{Id} $$

If you expand this out and re-arrange the terms, you'll get the expression you want:

$$ C(A-B) = A^{-1}B $$

**How I came up with this solution:**

The first thing I thought to do was a "change of variables". I thought let's give a name to $A-B$ and treat it as one single matrix. So I called it $X$:

$$ X := A-B $$

So then I re-wrote the original equation $(A-B)C = BA^{-1}$ using $X$ instead of $B$:

$$ XC = (A-X)A^{-1} = \mathrm{Id} - XA^{-1} $$

If you move the negative term to the other side and factor, you get

$$ X(C+A^{-1}) = \mathrm{Id} $$

Comment: Sorry, how did you know that $A-B$ is invertible, and how did you know it's inverse

Comment: I will update my solution with an explanation of how I came to this realization. I agree it is not obvious.